# Webscraping with R google searches

Tags: r, web-scraping, google-search

I am looking for a way to do webscraping with R on google searches. Given the dificulties (cookies and unstable tags), I however would like to share ideas on how a webscraping with R on google searches is still possible.

Here an example. I choose to google "ferrari" and try to retrieve the h3 for all the google search pages. I specially would like to get each h3 aref-links.

However, I just could retrieve the h3 tags and some other content.

```
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=ferrari'

first_page <- read_html(url)

h3 <- first_page %>%   
  html_nodes("a h3")

h3_links <- first_page %>%   
  html_nodes("a h3") %>% html_attr("href")


basic <- first_page %>%   
  html_nodes("span span")

paragraphs <- first_page %>%   
  html_nodes("div div")
```

Therefore, I just want to ask whether somebody knows how to webscrape on google searches for so many pages as possible. This could help in terms of finding a proper way to webscrape on google and discuss google tracking ways.

Comment: This would clearly break google ToS, they will block you in no time.

Comment: They already have a bunch information about everything. Since Google takes our and everyones data, why dont we track our data in Google?   In order to have an open discussion I prove @user12256545 contribution:

Comment: library(robotstxt)                                                           
robotstxt::paths_allowed("https://www.google.com/search?q=ferrari")   # No
                                                                                                                                       Therefore, I just want to ask whether there is another waz to bypass this hurdle like 
with RSelenium or through a Docker

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this :

```
extract_Info_By_Page <- function(page_Content)
{
  page <- read_html(page_Content)
  h3 <- page %>% html_nodes("a h3")
  h3_links <- page %>% html_nodes("a h3") %>% html_attr("href")
  basic <- page %>% html_nodes("span span")
  paragraphs <- page %>% html_nodes("div div")
  return(list(page = page, h3 = h3, 
              h3_links = h3_links, basic = basic,
              paragraphs = paragraphs))
}

library(RSelenium)
library(stringr)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

shell('docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()

first_Page <- 'https://www.google.com/search?q=ferrari'
remDr$navigate(first_Page)
page_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]

links_Other_Pages <- str_extract_all(page_Content, pattern = "\\<a.aria-label=(.*)\\</a\\>")
links_Other_Pages <- str_split(links_Other_Pages, pattern = "\\<a.aria-label")
links_Other_Pages <- str_extract_all(links_Other_Pages, 'href[^<]*\\<span class\\=\\\\')[[1]]
links_Other_Pages <- str_remove_all(links_Other_Pages, '\\<span class')
links_Other_Pages <- str_remove_all(links_Other_Pages, 'id|pnnext|style|text|align|left')
links_Other_Pages <- unlist(str_extract_all(links_Other_Pages, 'search.*[:alnum:]'))

links_Pages <- c(first_Page, links_Other_Pages)
nb_Pages <- length(links_Pages)
result_By_Page <- list()

for(i in 1 : nb_Pages)
{
  print(i)
  remDr$navigate(links_Pages[i])
  page_Content <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]
  result_By_Page[[i]] <- extract_Info_By_Page(page_Content)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Query:

   GET("http://google.com/", path = "search", query = list(q = "ferrari"))->google_ferrari

2.Define function:

```
extract_Info_By_Page <- function(page_Content)
{
  page<-read_html(page_Content)%>%html_nodes("body > div#main > div") %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = "//a[contains(@href, '/url?q=https://')]")
  
  #link
  page%>%grepl("\\bh3\\b", .)->page_with_h3
  page%>%html_attr("href")%>%
    data.frame(link=.,h3=page_with_h3)%>%filter(h3=="TRUE")%>%select(link)->link
  link$link%>%gsub("^[/]url[?]q=","",.)->link
  
  #h3 headliner
  page%>%html_text("span")%>%
    data.frame(headline=.,
               h3=page_with_h3)%>%filter(h3=="TRUE")%>%select(headline)->headline
  
  
  return(list(#page = page, if pagination would be included
              single_link = link,
              single_headline = headline))
}
```

3. Target site to parse:

   extract_Info_By_Page(google_ferrari)

It would be great to loop it over the query pages.